# HTTP authentication not working when switched to LIVE host

Tags: php, http, authentication, http-headers, authorization

Hey guys,
I'm stuck again, so where else to go than stackoverflow?
So heres the deal:
My site is set up and works fine on LOCALHOST.  I have an admin section of my site - nothing too fancy, but have used basic http authentication to protect it.
I have just FTP'd the whole lot over to the LIVE HOST directory and low and behold the HTTP authentication doesn't work.  Specifically, the username/password pop-up box appears with the correct details on it.  However, when I type in the correct login details the box doesn't let me on the page, it just reappears empty.
The authentication script is a separate file:

```
<?php
 // User name and password for authentication
 $username = 'USER';
 $password = 'PASSWORD';

if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) || !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) ||
($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] != $username) || ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] != $password)) {
// The user name/password are incorrect so send the authentication headers
header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="The Manor Cheadle"');
exit('<h2>The Manor Cheadle</h2>Sorry, you must enter a valid user name and 
password to access this page.');
}
?>

and is referenced at the top of every page:

<?php
require_once('authorize.php');
?>
```

Any ideas how to get round this and get it to work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What reappears empty, the login-prompt or the page? Do you by any chance run "safe mode" in live production?

Comment: the login-prompt returns empty and asks to you fill in the details again.  I dont know what you mean by 'safe mode' sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always used this for simple authentication, never had problems with it. But it looks very similar to yours.

```
<?
$auth = 0;
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']))
{
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Login"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    print "you need to login";
    exit;
}
else
{
    if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == "UserName" and $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] == "Password")
    {
        $auth=1;
    }
    else
    {
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Login"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        print "you need to login";
        exit;
    }
}

if ($auth==0) {
    print "you need to login";
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Nope, same issue.  I think you were right when you said similar to mine.  Thanks tho

Comment: Thanks for th help, unfortunately, I have had to get 1and1 to sort it out for me.  Even their tutorial on htaccess didn't work properly!  Rediculous!

Comment: I'm having the same problem with my site I just uploaded to 1and1. @Dan, what specifically did 1and1 do? Was it more than an htaccess file change?

Comment: Why was this checked as an answer when the OP said he had the same issue when he tried it? There isn't a successful answer.